# For which $a$ does the integral $\int_B||x||^{-a}dx$ exist, where $B:= \{ x\in \mathbb{R^2} :||x|| \leq1\} $?

Tags: integration

For which $a$ does the integral $\int_B||x||^{-a}dx$ exist. $B:= \{ x\in \mathbb{R^2} :||x|| \leq1\}  $

My solution was transforming into polar coordinates, $x=\cos(\phi)*r,y=\sin(\phi)*r$ such that I got the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r^{-a}\cdot r$ $drd\phi $ which resulted in  $(2\cdot \pi)/(-a+2)$. I was pretty confident in my result till I read that the answer was supposed to be $a<2$. Could someone clarify how one comes to this result?

Comment: Instead of `||`(two bars), it is advisable to use `\|` (backslash bar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluation of the integral is correct for $a < 2$, but not otherwise. Notice that you have

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 r^{1 - a} \, dr &= \frac{r^{2 - a}}{2 - a} \big|_{r = 0}^{r = 1} \\
\end{align*}
Now if $a < 2$, there are no issues at zero; but if $a \ge 2$, the expression does not make sense at zero - after all, for $a > 2$,
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^{2 - a}}{2 - a} = -\infty$$
and the integral is not finite.